# Magento 2.3 to Magento 2.4 migration

Tags: magento2.3, migration

Im currently switching servers and have installed a fresh Magento installation under version 2.4.3-p3. Our current store runds on magento 2.3.x. I want to migrate all customer data aswell as order data to the new server on the new version. It it safe to just copy the data from the database via export/import or is there a best practice that im missing?

Productwise im doing every product from scratch since we are switching extensions and want to reevaluate out catalog that way.

Comment: It won't be safe, or recommended to do it that way. You should upgrade via composer to go to higher version of Magento safely. If that's not possible, then use export/import features where possible to move data instead of copying tables directly.

Comment: Thougt so, i have already started to migrate data via export/import. Thanks for your reply.